# How can I Attached graphs in Email template in salesforce?

Tags: email, templates, salesforce

Is there any way to send email along with graph as an attachment or how can I include graphs into email and send it to particular user?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with either a Visualforce Email Template.  It requires knowledge of HTM, Visualforce, and Apex.  You may be able to get by with the Professional Edition and no Apex, but to really do anything powerful, you'd need the Enterprise Edition.
[Creating a Visualforce Email Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_intro.htm)

Comment: Thanks Matt, Is there any demo? so I can refer. Is it possible to develop it on my development org?

Comment: You definitely can do this in a developer org.  I don't know of any pre-built demo out there specifically for this.